# Binding KendoUI chart to database through webservice

Tags: asp.net, json, web-services, kendo-ui

I'm having some trouble binding a KendoUI chart to a remote database through a web service.

Here is my code:

```
    $("#chart").kendoChart({
    theme: $(document).data("kendoSkin") || "default",
    dataSource: {
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: "/WebServices/WebFunctions.asmx/RetrieveProjectCountByBMP",
                dataType: "json"
            }
        },
        schema: {
            model: {
                fields: {
                    Code: { type: "string" },
                    Count: { type: "number" }
                }
            }
        },
        sort: {
            field: "Code",
            dir: "asc"
        }
    },
    title: {
        text: "Project Count by BMP"
    },
    seriesDefaults: {
        type: "column"
    },
    series: [{
        field: "Count",
        name: "Project Count"
    }],
    categoryAxis: {
        field: "Code"
    },
    tooltip: {
        visible: true,
        format: "{0:N0}"
    }
});
```

and here is the web service code:

```
<WebMethod(EnableSession:=True)> _
Public Function RetrieveProjectCountByBMP() As Object
    Dim returnData = (From p As Project In Project.RetrieveAll() _
                     Join cs As ClaimScope In ClaimScope.RetrieveAll() On p.ProjectId Equals cs.ProjectId _
                     Join b As BMP In BMP.RetrieveAll On cs.BMPId Equals b.BMPId _
                     Where (p.ProjectMilestoneId = 17 Or p.ProjectMilestoneId = 18 Or p.ProjectMilestoneId = 19) _
                     And p.FiscalyearId = 5 _
                     Select b.Code, p.ProjectId).GroupBy( _
                        Function(bmpCode) bmpCode.Code _
                        , Function(proj) proj.ProjectId _
                        , Function(bmpCode, projects) New With {.Code = bmpCode, .Count = projects.Count()})

    Dim serializedReturnData As JavaScriptSerializer = New JavaScriptSerializer(returnData)

    Return serializedReturnData.Serialize(serializedReturnData)

    Return serializedReturnData
End Function
```

I've verified that my webservice returns a complete dataset. 
The problem is that when I run the code, the chart doesn't get populated. There are no error messages and no events fired in the event log.

The only issue I can find is that the webservice returns the data with leading a trailing quotes, like this:

"[{"Code":"1301","Count":239},{"Code":"1401","Count":178},{"Code":"1001","Count":33}]"

When I copy the data returned from the web service into a .json file and bind the chart to that, it works fine. However, I have to remove the leading and trailing quotes to get it to work.

How can I get my webservice to return my data in proper JSON format?

Thanks.

Comment: What do the developers tools say for the JSON call?  Is it returning a result of application/json?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this way:

```
Return Mid(serializedReturnData, 2, Len(serializedReturnData) - 2)
```